# Making a Facebook and Twitter sharing button appear in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, sharing

I'm creating an app, and I would like a Facebook sharing button to be hidden when the app starts up. After the user has pressed a button that starts an animation, I would like for the Facebook button to appear once the animation has finished.

The name of the button is postToFacebook. That button is a synthesized property of the ViewController.m

I've tried putting the following code in the viewDidLoad method:

```
[postToFacebook setHidden:YES];
```

Unfortunately, the button still appears when I start up the app (in the simulator, the build is successful.

The Facebook button is the standard:

```
- (IBAction)postToFacebook:(id)sender {



if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
    SLComposeViewController *facebookPost = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    [facebookPost setInitialText:@"initial text here"];

    [self presentViewController:facebookPost animated:YES completion:Nil];
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you create the button, same code work fine here.

Comment: When you debugged this, what was the value of `postToFacebook`?

Answer (score 0):

you are not supposed to have the same target action method as the property name.
It might confuse the system about what you are referring to exactly.

you should access the ivar via setter and getter, that is

```
[self.postToFacebookButton setHidden:YES]
```

Comment: I put [self.postToFacebbookButton setHidden:YES]; in the viewDidLoad method and the button is still visible at the beginning. Rats.